# Consequences of coherence in a monoidal category

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories, coalgebras

Let $\mathcal{D}_i = \left( D_i, \otimes_i, \mathbf{1}_i \right)$ be two cocomplete additive monoidal categories and let $\mathcal{F} \colon \mathcal{D}_1 \rightarrow \mathcal{D}_2$ be a strong monoidal equivalence of categories with tensor constraints isomorphisms $\mu_{X,Y} \colon \mathcal{F} \left( X \right) \otimes_2 \mathcal{F} \left( Y \right) \rightarrow \mathcal{F} \left( X \otimes_1 Y \right)$ and a unit isomorphism $\varepsilon \colon \mathbf{1}_2 \rightarrow \mathcal{F} \left( \mathbf{1}_1 \right)$.

1. Given an object $M \in D_1$, one can try and mimic the construction of the "tensor coalgebra" $T^c_{\otimes_1} \left( M \right) := \bigoplus_{i=0}^{\infty} M^{\otimes_1 i}$ together with the standard deconcatenation coproduct $\Delta \colon T^c_{\otimes_1} \left( M \right) \rightarrow T^c _{\otimes_1} \left( M \right) \otimes_1 T^c_{\otimes_1} \left( M \right)$. Formally, this involves choosing some specific bracketing for each $M^{\otimes_1 k}$ (say $M \otimes_1 \left( M \otimes_1 \left( \dots \otimes_1 \left( M \otimes_1 M \right) \right) \right)$ and then using various tensor product of associators to define the possible splittings of $m_1 \otimes_1 \left( m_2 \otimes_1 \left( \dots \left( m_{k-1} \otimes_1 m_k \right) \right) \right)$ into two parts $$\left( m_1 \otimes_1 \left( m_2 \otimes_1 \left( \dots \left( m_{i-1} \otimes_1 m_i \right) \right) \right) \right) \otimes_1 \left( m_{i+1} \otimes_1 \left( m_{i+2} \otimes_1 \left( \dots \left( m_{k-1} \otimes_1 m_k \right) \right) \right) \right) $$
   and so on. I would guess that the coherence theorem for monoidal categories will somehow imply that the resulting object is indeed an "associative coalgebra" (i.e, a comonoid in $\mathcal{D}_1$) but I'm not sure how to deduce it formally. Is this true?
2. Assuming the answer to the previous question is yes, set $C = T^c \left( M \right)$ and consider $\mathcal{F} \left( C \right)$. Since $\mathcal{F}$ is strong, we can endow $\mathcal{F} \left( C \right)$ with a comonoid structure by seting $\Delta_{\mathcal{F} \left( C \right)} = \mu_{C,C}^{-1} \circ \mathcal{F} \left( \Delta_C \right)$. On the other hand, the tensor constraints isomorphisms (together with the unit isomorphism) induce an isomorphism $\Phi$ between $\mathcal{F} (C) = \mathcal{F} \left( \bigoplus_{i=0}^{\infty} M^{\otimes_1 i} \right)$ and
   $\bigoplus_{i=0}^{\infty} \mathcal{F} \left( M \right)^{\otimes_2 i} = T^c_{\otimes_2} \left( \mathcal{F} (M) \right)$. I would guess that the isomorphism $\Phi$ is then an isomorphism of comonoids. To verify this it seems I need to check that various diagrams involving **both** the associators and the tensor constraints morphisms commute. Is this true and is there some coherence theorem which guarantees that this indeed works "for free"?

Comment: Additivity is superfluous. The hypothesis you need for 1 is that $\otimes$ preserves (= distributes over) coproducts in each variable. The usual coherence theorem should be good enough for 1 but I think you need a coherence theorem for monoidal functors for 2.

Comment: @ZhenLin: Thanks for your comment. I've used additivity because it holds in my specific situation but your comment got me wondering: The maps we naturally have are the maps $M^{\otimes k} \mapsto M^{\otimes k_1} \otimes M^{\otimes k_2}$ for $k_1 + k_2 = k$. In order to assemble them into a map $\oplus_{k=0}^{\infty} M^{\otimes k} \rightarrow \left( \oplus_{k_1=0}^{\infty} M^{\otimes k_1} \right) \otimes \left( \oplus_{k_2=0}^{\infty} M^{\otimes k_2} \right)$ it seems that I need the existence of finite biproducts. Then I can map $M^{\otimes k}$

Comment: into $\oplus_{k_1+k_2=k} M^{\otimes k_1} \otimes M^{\otimes k_2}$ and in turn map $\oplus_{k_1+k_2=k} M^{\otimes k_1} \otimes M^{\otimes k_2}$ into $\oplus_{k=0}^{\infty} M^{\otimes k} \rightarrow \left( \oplus_{k_1=0}^{\infty} M^{\otimes k_1} \right) \otimes \left( \oplus_{k_2=0}^{\infty} M^{\otimes k_2} \right)$. This doesn't seem to require distribution of $\otimes$ over the coproducts. Am I wrong?

Comment: Hmmm. Yes, maybe you don't need $\otimes$ to distribute over $\bigoplus$ if you only want a comultiplication. It is needed for multiplication and to show that it is universal (for multiplication).